# Modify a value in a dict using a setter

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict that looks as follows:

Initial Class

```
class Floors(object):
    def __init__(self, colour, speed, name):
        self.colour = colour
        self.speed = speed
        self.name = name
```

The dict in question

```
# Dict of info
floorTypes = {
    CONCRETE: Floors(CONCRETE, 5.5, 'Concrete'), # FFF
    MARBLE: Floors(MARBLE, 3.5, 'Marble'),       # FF3
    ...
    GRANITE: Floors(GRANITE, 6.0, 'Granite'),    # 777
    STEEL: Floors(STEEL, 1/100000, 'Steel')      # 000
    }
```

A Get method:

```
def getFloorType(rgb):
    return floorTypes.get(rgb)
```

I'm trying to be able to change the values based on a modifier that is passed in as a float. So if I pass in a modifier of 0.2, I want to make all the speeds equal to `(speed+(speed*0.2))`. I thought that the best way to go about doing that would be a `set` method, but when I try to run a foreach loop to set them, it doesn't work. Here is my loop, can you point out what I'm doing wrong?

current loop:

```
for floor in floorTypes:
    curSpeed = getFloorType(rgb).speed
    getFloorType(rgb).speed = curSpeed + (curSpeed * mult)
```

Where `mult` is a float multiplier, like `0.2` or `2.4`.

Here's the traceback that is returned:

```
ERROR:root:Traceback (most recent call last):
File "robot.py", line 360, in <module>
surfaceChanges(mult)
File "robot", line 330, in surfaceChanges
for i in floorTypes:
```

NameError: global name 'rgb' is not defined

Comment: What is wrong, you have a traceback ?

Comment: "Doesn't work" isn't a helpful error description.

Comment: @scharette sorry, I've added the traceback now to my problem description.

Comment: is the loop inside the function (getFloorType())?

Comment: @utengr no, it's in another function called `surfaceChanges`. In fact, it's the entirety of that method, and it takes in a float `mult` which is the modifier.

Comment: You didn't (and shouldn't) define a global `rgb` variable, all `rgb`s are only local to the functions they appear in. The error says you are using `rgb` without setting its value first.

Comment: Its very difficult to say anything from your current code. However, the error says that rgb is not defined in your code. I guess you are trying to use a local variable of another function in a different place with this for loop.

Comment: @MichaelButscher okay, thats easy enough to understand, so what would I need to do to _set_ a variable? I don't know how to create the setter since the getter is determined by the RGB value.

Comment: You want to set it for every floor type and you already have a loop which is run for each floor type (setting `floor` to the floor type) so you don't need `getFloorType(rgb)` to get the type you already have.

Comment: I got it! Thanks guys =)